# How to select dynamical every month different source folder in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Scenario : Actual i want to see that one when Sep 6 only data load for source folder sep6 and tomorrow SEP 7 then data load form SEP 7 folder only then day after tomorrow SEP 8 mean data load from sep8 folder only but how ?????

Comment: Assume today is September 1, is the process going to find a file in the SEP folder or does it need to look back a day? Assume "bad things happen" and today is September 2 but our process hasn't run for two days, how do you propose to pick up the AUG file(s)?

Comment: Actual i want to see that one 
when Sep 6 only data load for source folder sep6 and tomorrow SEP 7 then data load form SEP 7 folder only then day after tomorrow SEP 8  mean data load from sep8 folder only but how ?????

Comment: The way SO works, you write up what problem you're trying to solve and steps you've taken to do so. It sounds like from your comments, that you have more requirements that what you have in the question so click the Edit link and try improving your question with those facets in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by populating a variable from a C# script task. You can generate date/time strings very easily in a script task. E.g.:

```
Dts.Variables["User::FirstThreeCharsOfMonthNameUpper"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM").ToUpper();
```